# Is it possible to change/set the alarm clock from a different application on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, alarm

Is it possible to access information like the alarm clock time and change it from a different application on the iPhone.  And if its possible to do it, can it be approved by the app store to sell it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly do it—the CFPreferences API would probably be the right approach—but you definitely wouldn't get allowed into the App Store. If you're looking to make an alarm-clock application, check out the [Scheduling Local Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13) docs.