# How do I get access to iPhone Alarm?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, alarm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to change/set the alarm clock from a different application on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445293/is-it-possible-to-change-set-the-alarm-clock-from-a-different-application-on-the)

How do I get access to iPhone Alarm? I mean default Alarm app, not the Calendar. I would like to find out when the event is triggered and show a popup message instead of or right after the alarm was activated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this on an unjailbroken phone.

Comment: If it's not possible to do this - can someone refer me to Apple documentation where they mention this? And what would be the next best thing then?

Comment: Apple doesn't have docs listing all the things you can't do. Next best thing would be to write your own alarm app using local background notifications.